# Не обновляется список пакетов linux ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, update, apt-get

Облазил кучу форумов и сайтов но так и не нашел решения

Вот как это выглядит

```
padre@IdeaPad:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo apt-get update
Ошк:1 http://my.cool.repo.ubu/ubuntu jaunty InRelease
  Не удалось найти IP-адрес для «my.cool.repo.ubu»
Игн:2 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jaunty InRelease                     
Игн:3 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jaunty-updates InRelease             
Ошк:4 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jaunty Release                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 10.125.0.2 80]
Ошк:5 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jaunty-updates Release               
  404  Not Found [IP: 10.125.0.2 80]
Игн:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jaunty-security InRelease              
Игн:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jaunty InRelease                        
Ошк:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jaunty-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Ошк:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jaunty Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово            
E: Репозиторий «http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jaunty Release» не содержит файла Release.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, и поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Смотрите справочную страницу apt-secure(8) о создании репозитория и настройке пользователя.
E: Репозиторий «http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jaunty-updates Release» не содержит файла Release.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, и поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Смотрите справочную страницу apt-secure(8) о создании репозитория и настройке пользователя.
E: Репозиторий «http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jaunty-security Release» не содержит файла Release.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, и поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Смотрите справочную страницу apt-secure(8) о создании репозитория и настройке пользователя.
E: Репозиторий «http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jaunty Release» не содержит файла Release.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, и поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Смотрите справочную страницу apt-secure(8) о создании репозитория и настройке пользователя.
padre@IdeaPad:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$
```

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/old_ubuntu_versions

Comment: А ещё `10.*.*.*` это локалка. И твой мамонт ломится на соседний комп, который почему-то не отвечает.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu-9.04 (jaunty) не поддерживается уже 8 лет (с ноября 2010-го). С основных зеркал архивы репозиариев уже удалены. Архивные копии сохраняются сегодня на `old-releases.ubuntu.com`. Т.о. адреса в `/etc/apt/source.list` нужно будет заменит на манер:

```
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty main #...
```

Целесообразность такого использования весьма сомнительна — разве что исторический интерес.

Comment: если что я с сайта Xface скачивал дист. так как мне нужна была эта оболочка.

padre@IdeaPad:~/Рабочий стол$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic
padre@IdeaPad:~/Рабочий стол$

Comment: @ThicK значит ты или кто-то другой (возможно случайно) добавил/поменял имя релиза в `source.list` на древнее... в общем, ССЗБ.

Comment: как это исправить?

Comment: @ThicK, поправить `source.list` обратно... заменить `jaunty` на `bionic`. Заодно посмотреть файлы в `source.list.d` — возможно там просто лишняя копия репозитариев со старым релизом...

Comment: в source.list все нормально.
не знаю что это - source.list.d открываю через nano там пусто
я так понимаю там должны быть адреса на ПО но я не знаю как с ним работать
буду рад за помощь

Comment: `source.list.d` — просто директория, с тем же назначением, но позволяет организовать список репов в несколько файлов. если она пустая, то всё в порядке... если всё нормально, то что-то должно измениться... ошибки такие же? ЗЫ: собственно содержимое в студию или на `pastebin`.... ЗЗЫ: скрипт pastebinit может оказаться полезным

Comment: репозитории поменял. вот что вышло.
Игн:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Игн:2 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Игн:3 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Игн:4 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed InRelease
Игн:5 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Ошк:6 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release         
  404  Not Found [IP: 10.125.0.2 80]
Ошк:7 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release404  Not Found [IP: 10.125.0.2 80]

Comment: Ошк:8 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release 
  404  Not Found [IP: 10.125.0.2 80]
Ошк:9 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 10.125.0.2 80]
Ошк:10 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 10.125.0.2 80]
Сущ:11 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease      
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово                                   
E: Репозиторий «http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release» не содержит файла Release.

Comment: N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, и поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Смотрите справочную страницу apt-secure(8) о создании репозитория и настройке пользователя.
E: Репозиторий «http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release» не содержит файла Release.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, и поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
.

Comment: N: Смотрите справочную страницу apt-secure(8) о создании репозитория и настройке пользователя.
E: Репозиторий «http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release» не содержит файла Release.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, и поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Смотрите справочную страницу apt-secure(8) о создании репозитория и настройке пользователя.
E: Репозиторий «http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed Release» не содержит файла Release.

Comment: N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, и поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Смотрите справочную страницу apt-secure(8) о создании репозитория и настройке пользователя.
E: Репозиторий «http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports Release» не содержит файла Release.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, и поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Смотрите справочную страницу apt-secure(8) о создании репозитория и настройке пользователя

Comment: @ThicK не надо простынки дописывать в коментарии: или в вопрос (явно обозначив, что это дополнение), или на pastebin... по существу, во-первых, `xenial` — это 16.04, а если верить lsb-release у тебя `bionic`; во-вторых, как уже отметил один благородный дон, твоя бобро-суслико-заецелопа ломится в локалку... это свидетельствует об одном из: проблемы с твоим dns-сервером, лишняя запись в `/etc/hosts`, проблемы с прокси или фильтрацией доступа твоим провайдером... что-то конкетнее сказать сложно не зная конфигурации сети...